# how to read stderr into char[] in c

Tags: c, stderr

I have the code to check STDERR with 'DRM protected stream detected':

```
const static char* DRM_TOKEN = "DRM protected stream detected";

const char* source = argv[1];
char tempfile[80];
memset(tempfile, 0, 80);
snprintf(tempfile, 80, "stderr_%lld.log", av_gettime());
freopen(tempfile, "w", stderr);

fflush(stderr);
FILE *fp = fopen(tempfile, "r");
if(fp)
{
    char STDERR[256];
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
    memset(STDERR, 0, sizeof(char) * 256);
    fgets(STDERR, 256, fp);
    if(strstr(STDERR, DRM_TOKEN) != NULL)
    {
        drm = 1;
        break ;
    }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

It works, but I want to know any directly way to read STDERR into char[]. 
PS. my code will run in linux or macos.

Comment: Finally, I found the right way to get log messages from ffmpeg. It provides the function av_log_set_callback. I can use it to get all log messages directly. http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/log_8c.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stderr` was reopened in `"w"` mode, which is write-only. Judging from your `av_gettime` function, it looks like you're using `libavcodec`/`libavutil`, so instead of writing hideous hacks like this to get the error messages, you should read up on the `av_log` system and register your own logging function to override the default behavior of writing diagnostic messages to `stderr`.